# javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar not loded in liferay 6.1 and tomcat 7.0

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

With a custom plugin deployed, I'm getting the following error message and the webapp doesn't start:

validateJarFile(E:\6.1\liferay-portal-tomcat-6.1.1-ce-ga2-20120731132656558\liferay-portal-6.1.1-ce-ga2\tomcat-7.0.27\temp\4-SiteSkills_CMS-portlet\WEB-INF\lib\javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class

Why and how can I get rid of this message?

Comment: sorry it's tomcat 7.0

Comment: if you removed the jar from the lib folder your errors message probably changed, may you provide us with the new one. Also, please let us know how are you declaring the dependencies for this plug in.

Answer (score 0):

Do not package the servlet jar in an application's WEB-INF/lib directory. This jar comes with the appserver, tomcat in this case.

As your error message states the file to be in the temp folder: make sure you don't only remove the file from the webapps directory, but do a redeploy. Or just empty your temp folder

Comment: Thanks For Reply but i already remove servlet jar from WEB-INF/lib folder

Comment: Check the error message and clean the temp directory. That's where the offending file was found. Just removing it from the webapps directory doesn't trigger tomcat to redeploy an application